# What is the best way to pull out part of a jQuery application and refactor it's functionality into Vue?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an application. It's a "simple" editor, where you can select a list of items (for example, movies). When you edit an item, a jQuery dialog is opened where data can be entered.

I want to start separating out slowly some of the functionality into smaller Vue components. This way, each of the items (eg, a Movie or a Game) can be it's own separate Vue application.

The way that I am thinking about doing this for the moment is to continue using jQuery.dialog, but when the dialog box is open, to mount a new instance of Vue to the dialog box contents to present the information to be edited.

My Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/uL34Lq2e/1/

(Code duplicated bellow):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button class="btn" data-item="7">
Edit item #7 - Click here to show dialog box!
</button>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <div id="app-template" style="display:none">
    {{ message }}.<br />
    I have been clicked {{ runTimes }} {{ runTimes == 1 ? "time" : "times" }}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var externalData = {
  "7": {
    "runTimes": 0
  }
}


$(".btn").click(function() {

  var item = $(this).data('item')
  externalData[item].runTimes++;

t = document.querySelector("#app-template")
y = t.cloneNode(true);
y.style.display="block";
y.id="app";
t.parentElement.append(y)

  tim = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
      runTimes: externalData[item]['runTimes']
    }
  })


  $("#dialog-form").dialog( {
    width: 600,
    close: function() {
          document.querySelector("#app").remove()
          tim.$destroy()
    },
    buttons: {
        "Click to increase counter": function() {
          externalData[item].runTimes++;
          tim.$data.runTimes++;
          //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
  } )
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application refactoring to Vue.js from jQuery looks a good start.

However, it would be better to use Vue.js component to encapsulate your whole dialog. The strength of Vue.js is exactly the component orientation. Find the parent section (like, `<div id="app">...</div>` that can compose JavaScript logics with Vue.js, and in the Vue.js lifecycle (eg: `mounted`), use jQuery as a supplement. In your refactoring, better to always try to wrap the component with Vue.js.

https://jsfiddle.net/t49Lx31k/

[HTML]

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <dialog-component></dialog-component>
</div>
```

[JavaScript]

```
externalData = {
  "7": {
    "runTimes": 0
  }
 }

Vue.component("dialog-component", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button v-on:click="open" data-item="7">
        Edit item #7 - Click here to show dialog box!
      </button>

      <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <div id="app">
          {{ message }}.<br />
          I have been clicked {{ runTimes }} {{ runTimes == 1 ? "time" : "times" }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
      runTimes: 0
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    open() {
      $("#dialog-form").dialog("open")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 600,
      buttons: {
        "Click to increase counter": function() {
          externalData[item].runTimes++;
          //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          tim.$destroy()
          $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    })  
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

Comment: This is a good answer, the only thing is, I would expect that changing the `externalData` variable would update the contents of the dialog box.

Comment: I followed your original jsfiddle which did not work. Can I fix it as well?

Comment: You sure can! Sorry about the original, it was just a quick mockup of what I was trying to get done.